# How to connect mysql database in express.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using the mysql library for node.js and executing the following code:

```
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'example.com',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database:'databasename',


});

connection.connect();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
at Function.listen (/home/daniel/Desktop/100server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/daniel/Desktop/100server/server.js:33:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

I believe it has something to do with the host, should do something like mysql://example.com

Comment: Do you have `var mysql = require('mysql');` in your code? Just asking, since it is not written here. Also, did you have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp)?

Comment: Yes I do have it.

Comment: Also, are you using proper values for host, user,database and password?Are you running mysql locally? just checking

Comment: Yes I am connected to it with mysqlworkbench

Comment: which is the port you are running node?

Comment: Are you already running another app or service on port 3000? Your MySQL config is likely not the issue here. What is the code at (and surrounding) line 33 in your server.js file?